# Adding multiple JS files in Magento 2 using requirejs via custom theme

Tags: magento-2.1, requirejs

I have successfully added one js file using `requirejs-config.js`.

Code in `requirejs-config.js`

```
var config = {
    //when load requirejs will load following files also
    deps: [
        "js/main" //path to our main.js file. .js extension is not required.
    ]
}
```

Code in `main.js`

```
define([
        "jquery"
    ],
    function($)
    {
        "use strict";

        //our code goes here..
        console.log(" ====== Coming from Ved>Mytheme>Magento_Theme>web>js>main.js ====== ");

    }//main function ends here
);
```

**But now I want to add multiple JS files:**

1. modernizer.js
2. vendor.js **[ *This contains all 3rd party js. For ex. jQuery fancybox, flexslider, etc.* ]**
3. main.js **[ *This is already added but this should include after vendor.js* ]**

All above js files are present at:
*vendor_name/theme_name/Magento_Theme/web/js*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my code:

**requirejs-config.js:**

```
var config = {

     paths: {
        'flexslider': 'js/jquery.flexslider-min',
        'fancybox': 'js/jquery.fancybox' 
    },

    //when load requirejs will load following files also
    deps: [
        "js/main" //path to our main.js file. .js extension is not required.
    ],

    shim: {
        'flexslider' : 
        {
            deps: ['jquery']
        },
        'fancybox' : 
        {
            deps: ['jquery']
        }
    }
}
```

**main.js :**

```
    define([
            "jquery",
            "flexslider",
            "fancybox"
        ],
        function($)
        {
            "use strict";
            console.log(" ====== main.js is loaded====== ");
            $(window).load(function() 
            {
              //your code goes here..
            });
            $(document).ready(function() 
            {
              //your code goes here..
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 4):

Using `deps: [...]` in the `requirejs-config.js` suggests that your file will be loaded on every page. If you want to include your script in specific place You should use `map: {"*": {...}}`. You can include as many scripts as You need:

```
var config = {
    map: {
        "*": {
            "script1": "js/script1",
            "script2": "js/script2"
        }
    }
};
```

Then You can use this scripts with `data-mage-init` attribute or with `<script type="text/x-magento-init" />` tag. [Read more](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/javascript-dev-guide/javascript/js_init.html)

Modernizer You can find here `vendor/magento/magento2-base/lib/web/modernizr/modernizr.details.js`.

To include vendor plugins/libraries use the same way (with `map: {"*": {...}}`) and define them if needed in your script:

```
define(['jquery', 'some-plugin'], function($, some-plugin) {...});
```

The order of scripts including is not important because we use Asynchronous Module Definition (AMD).

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have added the code which worked for me.